# Path of a file in Macintosh

Tags: macos, excel, vba

I'm programming on Excel-Visual Basic with a Mac, I need to charge a dll but I don't know how to specify the total path of the file, and I don't know how to find it.
For example: on Windows it works by using "C:/ ..." and separating the following documents by /.

Comment: Office running on macos has no idea what a DLL is, they are Windows specific.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not the programming problem. OP needs to learn how to use use his OS

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the file in Finder
2. If you then hold the option button on your keyboard the `Copy {filename}` option in the context menu turns into `Copy {filename} as Pathname`
3. Click on that while still holding the option key and the path of the file is in your clipboard